# request nodejs package not being found

Tags: node.js, npm, sudo

I install request package using npm.
It appears to be located here:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/request/

```
var request = require("request");

request("http://www.google.com", function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

> module.js:340
>       throw err;
>             ^ Error: Cannot find module 'request'...

What do I need to alter or perform?
Further info, MAC OSX, node-v0.10.26.pkg, sudo -H npm install -g request, no errors

Comment: What command did you use to install the package? Were you in the same directory as your node app?

Comment: [npm and node without sudo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081293/install-npm-into-home-directory-with-distribution-nodejs-package-ubuntu/13021677#13021677)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have installed the package using the `-g` flag (global).
That's not how you should have installed the package.

To fix your problem, install the package locally:

```
npm install request
```

Or use a `package.json` file to persist the dependency:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: I found this advice (sudo -H npm install -g) due to the fact that npm was root. npm install request will not work. I'll look at package.json (I am new to nodejs).

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the package in your project directory, not globally. So run `npm install` from your project directory without the `-g` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Use advice by @Florent. Your direct problem, however, is that the global location is not known to node. If you still want to enable it, set the value of NODE_PATH to /usr/local/lib/node_modules (on Mac OS X in /etc/launchd.conf to make it available to all on boot).

Comment: This is how I install `nodeunit` for unit testing as I do not want to have it as a module dependency. Works like a charm.