# Unable to install yeoman on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) (PVHVM)

Tags: node.js, yeoman, ubuntu-16.04, npm-install

Hello everyone I am running into a problem that I can't seem to get my head around. I am setting up a server to deploy an app. The server is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) PVHVM. I have installed NVM and have installed all of my npm packages but for some reason I am **unable to install yeoman**. I have tried various solutions and none seem to work. Any ideas and or suggestions would be **greatly appreciated**.

**When I try to install yeoman with the following I get permission denied**

```
npm install -g yo
```

**Error:**

/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.4/bin/yo -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.4/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.4/bin/yo-complete -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.4/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/completion/index.js

> yo@2.0.0 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.4/lib/node_modules/yo
>   yodoctor
>   sh: 1: yodoctor: Permission denied
>   npm ERR! file sh
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>   npm ERR! syscall spawn
>   npm ERR! yo@2.0.0 postinstall: `yodoctor`
>   npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the yo@2.0.0 postinstall script.

**Solutions researched/attempted:**

[npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/1566

[Install NPM into home directory with distribution nodejs package (Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081293/install-npm-into-home-directory-with-distribution-nodejs-package-ubuntu/13021677#13021677)

Comment: Try with sudo...

Comment: I tried sudo and I get the same error

Comment: I think you made a mess... how come that without sudo your home is /root and the error is complaining about permissions... you are not doing this with the user to whom npm belongs..

Comment: What is the output for `which npm`

Comment: This is my first time using ubunto. I try really hard not to make a mess. Let me explain my steps and you can tell me if I did something wrong.

1) installed ubuntu
2) sudo apt-get update
3) sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
4) curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
5) Relaunced terminal
6) npm install -g yo

Comment: To answer your question about root, I used ssh root@myipaddress from my terminal. Should I not be using root to ssh

Comment: I enter as root only in extreme situations... usually it's preferable to create a user and give it all it needs - least privileged approach - much safer.

Answer (score 0):

try uninstall nvm then remove ~/.nvm folder
and install it from script

do

`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash`

add that line in ~/.bashrc

`export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion`

Comment: that is exactly what I have in my bashrc file

Comment: I will run the steps you provided to make sure

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback I received I created a new user, gave that user sudo, installed nvm, installed nvm install stable and was then able to install yeoman without any errors