# node.js install web3 module scrypt issue

Tags: node.js, npm, gyp, scrypt

All I want is to install web3 in my node.

My node version is v8.9.4
web3 version is 1.0.0-beta.46

But what I don't understand is that the scrypt keeps failing.
I just run the node, I see the terrible message that no scrypt module I have...

Usually I just install my module not -g option but --save one.
However I can't solve my problem so I just install scrypt with -g option

```
# npm install -g scrypt
```

But the error message I cannot understand why it happen to me?

```
# npm install -g scrypt

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall /opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js

Error: Error: Command failed: ./configure
./configure: line 1904: config.log: Permission denied
./configure: line 1914: config.log: Permission denied


> scrypt@6.0.3 install /opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/scrypt/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/opt/nodejs/bin/node" "/opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-15T10_44_58_509Z-debug.log
```

I try to reinstall web3 into my module,
The message will be shown. I think node gyp is the key to this problem, so can I ask you for advice on why this problem is happening?

```
> scrypt@6.0.3 install /home/my_apps/node/node_modules/scrypt.js/node_modules/scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/my_apps/node/node_modules/scrypt.js/node_modules/scrypt/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/opt/nodejs/bin/node" "/opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/my_apps/node/node_modules/scrypt.js/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 

> scrypt@6.0.3 install /home/my_apps/node/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/scrypt.js/node_modules/scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/my_apps/node/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/scrypt.js/node_modules/scrypt/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/opt/nodejs/bin/node" "/opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/my_apps/node/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/scrypt.js/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: scrypt@6.0.3 (node_modules/scrypt.js/node_modules/scrypt):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13021677/10722053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the error tells you that you don't have proper access to the file system to write into those folders.

My first thought was, that you're just not allowed to write in the folder where the 'globals' are installed, but in the second try I think you're showing to do it in your usual folder.
So, when you try to install as --save, does it still give you the error? And it's only for this module?
Is it possible that you can gain more rights to write into these folders?

Comment: Thank you Reder :) I found that the problem is root account. I'd changed normal user then the problem has been completely resolved. This is a special case I think.. Thanks to you I can track my issue then finally I'm able to solve my issue. You save my days Thank you :)

Comment: I have the problem with this in 2020. root fails as well as local user